# Prevent from "Kernel appears to have died"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a quite time-taking code in a Jupyter Notebook. At each iteration, it gives me a matrix, let's say `a.` I would like to store in a "safe" place (i.e., in a file for example) all these matrices. How to do that?

Indeed, I had launched my script for some time, and all worked well, but then it showed "Kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically," and all my variables had disappeared, losing all.

How to prevent from this?

I do mention that, as I am working on a VM, I can't use anything but Jupyter notebook

So to be clear, my question is : how to prevent losing my variables in a long-time-taking loop, which can happens due to a dying kernel ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your primary goal to keep the kernel from dying or to store your matrices?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My primary goal is of course to "save" my work and avoid needing to restart the execution. Actually, if the kernel doesn't die, the execution will come to an end, the matrices will keep being there, and I could use them for the following cells...